Anon PL/SQL block to test FUNCTION with return of REF CURSOR and OUTPUT variable
I have a FUNCTION inside a PACKAGE which ALSO has an OUTPUT variable
create package sum_pkg

TYPE rc is REF CURSOR;

function sum_detail
(
    p_name in varchar2,
    p_out  out varchar2
)
return rc
as
   begin
   ...
end;

/
I am testing as follows but getting error:
    var x REFCURSOR;

    exec :x := sum_pkg.sum_detail ( p_name = 'abc', p_out => :x ) ;

    print :x

But I am getting : Identifier X must be declared.

Your call doesn't match your function - though it's hard to tell with partial/psuedocode for your package. The function has p_out as a varchar not a ref cursor, and doesn't declare a local rc variable; but then also doesn't show p_out being set, or the return form the function. In your call, p_name = 'abc' should be p_name => 'abc'. (That would cause an PLS-00201, but for p_name, not x.) A [mcve] would be helpful.

See similar question - you can't call a function with an OUT parameter from a SELECT statement.

You are returning a cursor and a string, you need two variables:
VARIABLE x REFCURSOR;
VARIABLE y VARCHAR2(10);

EXECUTE :x := sum_pkg.sum_detail( p_name = 'abc', p_out => :y ) ;

PRINT :x
PRINT :y

Then, if you are using SQL Developer, run the SQL file as a script using F5 or the icon with a green triangle with a page behind it (don't use Ctrl + Enter, or the green triangle icon, as it only runs a single statement and not the entire script).

Are you sure you want to return two values? Code suggests that function returns ref cursor, along with OUT parameter. If you are, then here's an example which shows how to do that.
Function is based on Scott's sample schema; function accepts employee name, finds their job (which is then returned via OUT parameter), while ref cursor returns all employees who share the same job.
SQL> create or replace function sum_detail
  2    (p_name in varchar2,
  3     p_out  out varchar2)
  4  return sys_refcursor is
  5    rc sys_refcursor;
  6  begin
  7    select job into p_out
  8    from emp
  9    where ename = p_name;
 10
 11    open rc for select ename from emp
 12      where job = p_out;
 13
 14    return rc;
 15  end;
 16  /

Function created.

Testing: you'll have to declare all variables you need, which include the one that accepts OUT parameter, as well as ref cursor. Additional variable (l_ename) is needed to show (in a loop, with dbms_output.put_line) what ref cursor actually contains.
SQL> set serveroutput on;
SQL> declare
  2    l_job varchar2(20);
  3    l_rc  sys_refcursor;
  4    l_ename varchar2(20);
  5  begin
  6    l_rc := sum_detail('SCOTT', l_job);
  7
  8    loop
  9      fetch l_rc into l_ename;
 10      exit when l_rc%notfound;
 11      dbms_output.put_line(l_ename);
 12    end loop;
 13  end;
 14  /
SCOTT
FORD

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL>

